# How can I add description to Facebook like button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

Related to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413502/text-only-version-of-facebooks-like-button), I coded a simple Facebook like link as:

```
<a href="JavaScript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://jsfiddle.net','','width=657,height=400,scrollbars=1')">Like</a>
```

How can I add a personal description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the required Open Graph tags to the link you want to share:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags
- http://ogp.me/

That being said, if you want to add a "message", that´s not possible at all and not allowed anyway. The message always must be 100% user generated and prefilling is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using `sharer.php` [anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956229/has-facebook-sharer-php-changed-to-no-longer-accept-detailed-parameters).

Using the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3) is the easiest alternative, but for more features I'd advise using their [custom OG stories API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom).